# How to put a background image in a webpage with a header

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

What I have to begin with: http://jsbin.com/opokev/39

**Problems**

- the image scales and compresses according to the browser window size. For example If I open firebug (which takes half of the page) the background image compresses and does not look good.

**Requirements**

- I don't want the image to be cut off from the bottom or up
- I need a Header on top that is about `85px`
- I don't want the horizontal or vertical scrollbar on the webpage.

I've asked questions before but have gotten mixed answers, I'm really struggling with this.  I am trying to get something like the background image on [livingsocial.com](http://livingsocial.com) only difference being that I don't want my header to take over part of the image like theirs.

Answer (score 2):

I see your background image problem. You have it set as an image in a div. Why not get rid of that, and just apply the following to the css:

```
body {
background-image: http://i53.tinypic.com/347a8uu.jpg;
background-repeat:none;

}
```

Or if for some reason you need to keep it as a div, just get rid of `position: absolute;`

For the header, just add a div right after `<body` like so:

```
<div class="header_wrapper"></div>
```

And the css:

```
.header_wrapper {

width: 85px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: I've implemented your solution but that adds a scrollbar on the webpage: http://jsbin.com/opokev/78  ....will the scrollbar be OK when I start adding content to the webpage?  I would like to NOT have the scrollbar though.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a background then why are you adding it as an img?

CSS...

```
background:url("http://i53.tinypic.com/347a8uu.jpg" center top no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: you may or may not want to use background-size:cover; as this makes the image scale with the window...  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: adding `center top` does show the image however, again, it is being cut off: http://jsbin.com/opokev/81

Comment: I'm not seeing anything cut off. I suggest you clear your browser cache and look again... It should be working fine.